# `rails s -p` command not catched by docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a small project with one service which is a rails API:. The container holding that rails API is not behaving as I'd like it to.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mynab_api:
    image: 'myname/my_api:latest'
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` of the service:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3-alpine3.8

# Minimal requirements to run a Rails app
RUN apk add --no-cache --update build-base \
                                linux-headers \
                                git \
                                sqlite-dev \
                                nodejs \
                                tzdata

ENV APP_PATH /usr/src/app

# Different layer for gems installation
WORKDIR $APP_PATH
ADD Gemfile $APP_PATH
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_PATH
RUN bundle install

# Copy the application into the container
COPY . $APP_PATH

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-p", "3001"]
```

When I run `$ docker-compose up` the service starts up and doensn't crash. If I run `$ docker-compose ps` the service is up. The issue is that if I go into the browser to `http://localhost:3001`, the service seems to be down (though still up).

A fix that I found is to replace the default command in the `Dockerfile` (CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-p", "3001"]) by

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

which by default emits on the port 3000. Then in the `docker-compose.yml` I map the port 3001 on my machine to the port 3000 in my container.

```
version: '3'

services:
  mynab_api:
    image: 'myname/my_api:latest'
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
```

This works find. Why isn't the first version working ?

Edit: Here is what `telnet` gives

```
-> % telnet localhost 3001
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: What is the console output of rails?

Comment: That's an issue I failed to mention. I get no console output and no logs. But I'm pretty sure the rails app is running because 1. `$ docker-compose ps ` shows that the container is `up`. It wouldn't be if the main process had stopped. and 2, if I open a bash session inside the container and run `$ ps -aux` I see that there is a process running on port 3001.

Comment: could you provide the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep 3001` with your initial version?

Comment: I use a mac so I don't have netstat. I added the telnet output in an edit. I don't know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can modify your `docker-compose.yml` as below to see server output on the screen:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mynab_api:
    image: 'myname/my_api:latest'
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    tty: true
```

You should also try modifying the `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` as below:

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-p", "3001", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

If you run `rails server --help` you'll see the following for the `--binding` flag:

```
Binds Rails to the specified IP - defaults to 'localhost' in development 
and '0.0.0.0' in other environments'
```

You'll find that you need to specify this flag when you're using docker containers (in development at least) or running a virtual machine (Virtualbox or others).

Answer (score 0):

By default rails docker container run on 3000 port. If you want to run on different port than you need to map inner container port to outer app. Like in this way:

```
ports:
 - '3001:3000'
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my question. I found that fix. My questions is 'why does it stop working as soon as I run rails on another port ? (provided I change the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to modify the default port in your `config/puma.rb` file.

```
ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3001 }
```

That way you can use the following command in your `Dockerfile`

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server"]
```